# Power Bi in Website laravel

Tags: laravel, powerbi

I have a power bi dashboard in my website called using the iframe. But it shows all the employee details. How can I make the dashboard to display only the data of the current logged in employee

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't because this scenario is not supported.  When you say your dashboard is in an iframe I asssume you used publish to web and have linked to the dashboard using the embed code.  Publish to web does not support authentication.  See the warning here regarding this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web.

The end user would need to access the dashboard through the Power BI service to use authentication.  Without an authenticated user you would have no way of filtering the report.

There are a bunch of prerequistes and steps to get this working. You might want to start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/integrate-report where you can find details of the Rest API and the Azure AD App registration requirements, access token requirements and sample code to call the report and embed it in a div in a web page.  Like I said at the top, I've assumed you've not done any of this yet since you only mention publishing the report via an iframe so its difficult to give more specific guidance.